# when FragmentTransaction call show method?

Tags: java, android, fragment, fragmenttransaction

I want transition fragment A to fragement B.
fragment A transaction code is

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.hide(this);
ft.add(R.id.front_side_container , detail);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

in fragment A code, `ft.hid(this)` <- I hide fragment A

code in fragment B

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

when call `popBackStack()`, I don't call `FrangmentTransaction.show()`

but fragment A appear. why? I don't call `show()`

is correct automatically called `show()` when execute `popBackStack()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fragment framework will automatically handle showing the last element in the backstack when you call 'popBackStack()', so yes, it's 100% correct.

If you called .hide(), it will call .show(), and if you didn't call .hide() (meaning the old fragment is destroyed), it will create a completely new one and show that.